# A series aproximation for measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

I've been working on this problem and I don't know how to face it. If $(X,M)$ is a  measurable space and $f:\mathbb{X}\longrightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function then exist a collection of measurable sets $(A_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a sequence of real numbers $(c_{i})_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $f=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}c_{i}\chi_{A_{i}}$. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: To start with, can you find such a linear combination $s$ so that $s \le f$ and $f - s \le 1$ everywhere?

Comment: Yes, you can aproximate $f$ by a monotone sequence of simple functions $(f_{n})$ on $X$. In particular there exists one $f_{k}$ such that $f-f_{k}\leq 1$. And $f_{k}=\sum_{i={1}}^{r}c_{i}\chi_{A_{i}}$ for some $c_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_{i}\in M$

Comment: Can you get within $1/2$?  Within $1/4$?  Might these suggest how to do the thing in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is all I can think of.  Suppose first that $f:X \to [0,1]$.  Then
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \chi_{A_n} $$
where $A_n = \{x:\text{the $n$th base 2 digit of $f(x)$ is 1}\}$.  This should easily extend to $f:X \to [0,\infty]$.